# angularjs bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

i am using bootstrap datepicker with angular js...

https://gist.github.com/rsvalerio/5606688

https://gist.github.com/danbarua/5356062

according to it.. if i need to pass options to the datepicker it should be like:

```
<input type="text" b-datepicker="{format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'}" ng-model="dateObject" >
```

but this is not working. i am not able to fix the code, please help

Comment: can you create a jsFiddle with an example?

Comment: In case somebody else comes across this question, see here: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Datepicker` with `AngularStrap` instead of `AngularUI` because it's more recent: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/1.0/#/datepicker (so far bootstrap 2 only)

Comment: AngularStrap doesn't return a Date() object, which Angular uses. Correct me if I'm wrong. But be careful before you invest very much time in it.

Comment: Have a look at http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ search for ui.bootstrap.datepicker - its now part of the latest and it works really well

Comment: AngularStrap author's here, the latest native version of the plugin (http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##datepickers) does handle any type and defaults to a Date type.

Answer (score 5):

The gist urls you gave are forks. So I decided to check what was the original source. 
The [first gist](https://gist.github.com/oborder/3103533) says:

> based on sample from Peter Bacon Darwin (jqUi)
>   https://github.com/petebacondarwin/angular-ui/tree/angular-v1.0/modules/directives/date

If you click there, the url is gone. But https://github.com/petebacondarwin/angular-ui/ still exists and is only a fork for angular-ui. And if you check angular-ui, you'll find:

https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/tree/master/modules/directives/date

Which seems to be the result of that old code evolved.

Here you can see it on action: 
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-date/

**Conclusion**: Just use [ui-date](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/tree/master/modules/directives/date), instead of that old forked gist code.

Comment: it is using jquery ui datepicker... i want to use bootstrap-datepicker